# how to sort query data with aws-amplify (CRUD of aws-amplify by default)?

Tags: sorting, backend, aws-amplify

I'm making a request to retrieve data from posts with the API, in my listTodo request I want to add sort the data to filter the data according to the date of their creation to put them in an order, but since it's the backend aws-amplify by default, I don't know how to do that.

```
export const listTodos = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListTodos(
    $filter: ModelTodoFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listTodos(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        title
        content
        email
        coverImage
        images
        page
        language
        dateAndLocation
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
```

I already try:

- add in setting sortDirection: ASC or sortDirection: DESC
- add in setting queryField: "todosByDate", sortKeyFields: ["createdAt"]
- lots of other try

Can anyone tell me how to sort the data in this query, sort by creation date ?

Answer (score 1):

here is a few possibilities you can explore:

**Global secondary index's**:
One option is to create an index (global secondary index in dynamodb) on the part that you want to filter. To do that you have to update your graphql model. The model below will give you a query where you can retrieve all todos based on a language, and sort the data based on the createdAt field.

```
type Todo @model {
  id: ID!)
  title: String
  content: String
  email: String
  coverImage: String
  images: String
  page: Int
  language: String @index(name: "todosByLanguage", queryField: "todosByLanguage", sortKeyFields: ["createdAt"])
  dateAndLocation: String
  createdAt: AWSDateTime
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime
}
```

You will then be able to do a query, called TodosByLanguage where you can pass inn the sort direction. This query will require an input for language.

**Adding a sort key to your main index:** There is also the possibility to give expand your original key (ID field) with a sort key.

```
type Todo @model {
  id: ID! @primaryKey(sortKeyFields: ["createdAt"])
  title: String
  ...
}
```

I haven't done this approach before so I am not sure exactly how it will work. But you might be able to sort the data on the createdAt field with this. But this changes the core behaviour of your dynamoDB table, for example you might night to pass inn the sort key (createdAt) when you will retrieve one single item, or update items. So make sure you do this in a dev environment before you try.

**Elasticsearch / Opensearch**
The last solution is to add @searchable to your model. This will stream all your data in the todo table into an elasticsearch (only new ones, existig data won't automatically be streamed over). But be aware, elasticsearch is run on rented servers and can be expensive (depending on your budget).

```
type Todo @searchable @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String
  ...
}
```

Opensearch is much more flexible in doing queries than dynamoDB. And you will here be able to search and sort almost everything in the way you want it to be queried.

**Edit**
Elasticsearch is now called Opensearch in aws

Comment: Can an `@index` be added to the `id` field instead of using the `@primaryKey`?